# How to get HWND of an embedded web browser control in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, mfc

I'm using the embedded [web browser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx) in my dialog-based MFC window and I need to know the HWND of the web browser control in it. I was able to find the following code that claims to retrieve it:

```
HWND hWndWebBrowser = NULL;

LPUNKNOWN unknown = m_browser.GetControlUnknown();

IWebBrowser2* pWB = NULL;
if(SUCCEEDED(unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,(void **)&pWB)))
{
    CComPtr<IServiceProvider> pServiceProvider;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pWB->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void**)&pServiceProvider)))
    {
        CComPtr<IOleWindow> pWindow;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pServiceProvider->QueryService(SID_SShellBrowser, IID_IOleWindow, (void**)&pWindow)))
        {
            SHANDLE_PTR hBrowser = 0;
            if (SUCCEEDED(pWindow->GetWindow(&hBrowser)))
            {
                hWndWebBrowser = (HWND)hBrowser;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(unknown)
{
    unknown->Release();
}
```

but the problem is that when it runs, it returns a handle, but not the one I would expect. The best way to illustrate it is with this Spy++ screenshot:

[image]

I understand that I can use [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look for a window with the `Internet Explorer_Server` class, but I'm somewhat concerned about using this undocumented class name.

Does anyone have a better way to retrieve that (web browser) window handle?

Comment: Does sound a bit like an XY problem. Why do you need that specific HWND? What makes it special? Because that may be the kye to your answer.

Comment: You are concerned about using the class name? But once you have the window handle, you should have the exact same concerns over what you do with that window handle. What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There are multiple legit uses for that handle. Here's one just off the top of my head. I need to know whether or not the browser control had a keyboard focus (the outcome will influence the selection in a popup dialog) so I do `bool bHadFocus = ::GetFocus() == hIEWnd;` but for that to work I need to know `hIEWnd`.

Comment: Not my point. My point is that if you are concerned about the robustness across versions, those concerns exist even once you've found the window handle

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes I hear you but it is less likely to happen. My concern now is that Microsoft may phase out IE and thus this control may have a new class name, anything like `Spartan_Server` or such.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Obtaining the HWND for the WebBrowser control](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/244310), you can use following function to retrieve HWND.

```
IOleWindow *pOWin;
HWND hBWnd;

HRESULT hRes = m_pBrowserApp->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (void **)&pOWin);
if (SUCCEEDED(hRes)) {
    hRes = pOWin->GetWindow(&hBWnd);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes)) {
        // Place hBWnd-manipulating code here
    }
pOWin->Release(); // Missing from the MS example
}
```

Because the class names (`Shell DocObject View` and `Internet Explorer_Server`) could change, the above code should be preferred, although it is unlikely given the fact that Internet Explorer is now discontinued.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it gives me the exact same result as my code above.

Comment: @c00000fd Did you add `poWin->Release();`?

Answer (score 1):

The lexical of the question is a little tricky.

The HWND of the (Web Browser) is indeed the answer
that you posted and the answer posted by Santosh Dhanawade.

When a document is loaded, the web browser control creates a
new window or iframe, see the [DWebBrowserEvents2::DocumentComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

> Event handler parameters: 
>   " *pDisp [in]* "
>
> A pointer to the IDispatch interface of the window or frame in which the document is loaded. This IDispatch interface can be queried for the IWebBrowser2 interface.

so, changing the question:

"Does anyone have a better way to retrieve that (**web browser**) window handle?"

to:

"Does anyone have a better way to retrieve that (**window or iframe**) window handle?"

we have that the window or iframe HWND that you are locking for,
will be abailable after that the document has been completed loaded.

Which means that we can do the follow:

Implement a DocumentComplete event handler throw a raw c or c++ implementation of 
IDispatch or an ATL DispEventImpl or ATL DispEventSimpleImpl.
See [Understanding COM Event Handling](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/9014/understanding-com-event-handling).

Sink our event handler into the the web browser control to get the events report.

And get the window or iframe HWND from the DocumentComplete event:

assuming a raw c++ IDispatch implementation:

```
IFACEMETHODIMP DWebBrowserEvents2Impl::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS * pDispParams, VARIANT * pVarResult, EXCEPINFO * pExcepInfo, UINT * puArgErr)
{
    if (dispIdMember == DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE) {
        VARIANT variantDispatch;
        VariantInit(&variantDispatch);
        HRESULT hr = DispGetParam(pDispParams, 0, VT_DISPATCH, &variantDispatch, NULL);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {            
            IOleWindow* iOleWindow;
            hr = variantDispatch.pdispVal->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (LPVOID*) &iOleWindow);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                HWND hwnd;
                hr = iOleWindow->GetWindow(&hwnd);
                iOleWindow->Release();
                if (SUCCEEED(hr)){
                //now the hwnd correponds to the Internet Explorer_Server window.
                //Do what ever you want with the HWND handler.              
                }  
            }           
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the window we're looking for is a direct descendance of the CHtmlView derived CWnd, so I use this hack to get the window and set the focus to it:

```
static CWnd* findChildWebbrowser(CWnd* pWnd) {
    if(pWnd == NULL) { return NULL; }
    CWnd* pC = pWnd->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
    if(pC == NULL) { return NULL; };
    CString buf;
    ::GetClassName(pC->GetSafeHwnd(), buf.GetBuffer(2048), 2047);
    buf.ReleaseBuffer();
    if(buf == _T("Internet Explorer_Server")) {
        return pC;
    }
    return findChildWebbrowser(pC);
}

void CMyWebView::OnSetFocus(CWnd* pOldWnd) {
    // CHtmlView::OnSetFocus(pOldWnd);
    CWnd* pIE = findChildWebbrowser(this);
    if(pIE!=NULL) {
        // this makes cursor/page keys work
        pIE->SetFocus();
        // this makes the TAB key work
        pIE->SendMessage(WM_LBUTTONDOWN);
        pIE->SendMessage(WM_LBUTTONUP);
    }
}
```